# Instagram AuthDialog Cutting in android?

Tags: android, instagram

When i am launching dialog view at that time auth dialog cutting view in android.
[image]

```
package com.ingreets.app.instagram;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Display 37Signals authentication dialog.
 *
 * @author Thiago Locatelli <thiago.locatelli@gmail.com>
 * @author Lorensius W. L T <lorenz@londatiga.net>
 */
public class InstagramDialog extends Dialog {

    private static final String TAG = "Instagram-WebView";
    private String mUrl;
    private OAuthDialogListener mListener;
    private ProgressDialog mSpinner;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private LinearLayout mContent;
    Context context;
    private int width=0;
    private int height=0;
    public InstagramDialog(Context context, String url,
                           OAuthDialogListener listener,int width,int height) {
        super(context);
        this.context=context;
        mUrl = url;
        Log.i(TAG,"Authentication Url"+url);
        mListener = listener;
        this.width=width+10;
        this.height=height+10;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        mSpinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mSpinner.setMessage("Loading...");
        mContent = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        mContent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        setUpWebView();

        addContentView(mContent, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                width,height));
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getContext());
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
    }

    private void setUpWebView() {
        mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
        mContent.addView(mWebView);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new OAuthWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
       // mWebView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width,width));
      //  mWebView.setPadding(0,20,0,0);

   }

    public interface OAuthDialogListener {
        public abstract void onComplete(String accessToken);
        public abstract void onError(String error);
    }

    private class OAuthWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Redirecting URL " + url);

            if (url.startsWith(InstagramApp.mCallbackUrl)) {
                String urls[] = url.split("=");
                mListener.onComplete(urls[1]);
                InstagramDialog.this.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Page error: " + description);

            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            mListener.onError(description);
            InstagramDialog.this.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading URL: " + url);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mSpinner.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
           /* String title = mWebView.getTitle();
            if (title != null && title.length() > 0) {
                mTitle.setText(title);
            }*/
            Log.d(TAG, "onPageFinished URL: " + url);
            mSpinner.dismiss();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: You would need to show us the XML - to me it looks like the WebView is the thing that is going over

Comment: @psyco u can see in image login button is cutting

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon no i have added dynamically webview i am not using any layout for this

Comment: Ok well what I am saying is that I think the HTML inside the WebView is wider than the WebView itself. Have you tried it in landscape mode?

Comment: Solved i have used custom layout set for dialog and it is working

Comment: @Mahesh I'm facing the same issue, what does your custom layout look like?